# I'm trying to run a logistic regression on R and am getting this error

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

> model <- glm(morning ~ time since arrival this dry season (days).,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=raw_data_1)
> Error: unexpected symbol in "model <- glm(morning ~ time since"

below are the heading for my data:
Bear ID/
Date DMY/
sighting occurred in morning (0/1)/
time since arrival this dry season (days)

this is a sample of my data:

`dput(head(raw_data_1,10))`

```
structure(list(`Bear ID` = c("Cobalt", "Pazu", "Fang", "McQueen", 
"Mushroom", "Umber", "Umber", "Fang", "Teto", "Eggplant"), `Date DMY` = structure(c(1463011200, 
1464480000, 1464825600, 1464825600, 1465084800, 1466380800, 1466467200, 
1467590400, 1468886400, 1470182400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `sighting occurred in morning (0/1)` = c(0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `time since arrival this dry season (days)` = c(72, 
89, 93, 93, 96, 111, 112, 125, 140, 155)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm trying to carry out a logistic regression to model the probability of being seen in the morning relative to time since arrival this dry season. Massive R rookie, first model I have had to make.

Comment: Use a quote ' for column names with spaces such as 'time since arrival this dry season (days)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this as mentioned in comments:

```
#Code
glm(raw_data_1$'sighting occurred in morning (0/1)' ~
      raw_data_1$'time since arrival this dry season (days)',
    family=binomial(link='logit'),data=raw_data_1)
```

Output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = raw_data_1$"sighting occurred in morning (0/1)" ~ 
    raw_data_1$"time since arrival this dry season (days)", family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = raw_data_1)

Coefficients:
                                           (Intercept)  
                                              -4.17519  
raw_data_1$"time since arrival this dry season (days)"  
                                               0.04337  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
Null Deviance:      13.46 
Residual Deviance: 11.58    AIC: 15.58
```

Comment: Thank you Duck - It comes up with this though:Error in model.frame.default(formula = raw_data_1$morning ~ raw_data_1$"time since arrival this dry season (days).",  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'raw_data_1$morning'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `morning`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `time since arrival this dry season (days).`.

Comment: Could you please use `dput(raw_data_1)` and paste the output in your question to reproduce your issue?

Comment: as in you want me to paste all the data into the question?

Comment: @LLLLFFFF Just a sample using `dput(head(raw_data_1,10))`

Comment: is that what you were after?

Comment: @LLLLFFFF I have added an update for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry - just finally - how do I then graph the anova results?

Comment: First, save the model in an object like `mod <- glm(....)` then use this `plot(anova(mod))`

Comment: @LLLLFFFF Also please read the info I shared with you!

Comment: That creates a series of boxes with data around the edge - I am looking to create a line chart with a line marking how probability of morning sighting is affected over time. Do you know how to get to this point?

Comment: @LLLLFFFF You would need to store the predicted values in a vector after using `predict()` and then use `plot()` or `ggplot2()` to reach the S shape plot.

Comment: having done that it says my figure margins are too large ?

Comment: @LLLLFFFF Try with `ggplot2`